# "Переходы" по страницам сайта

Tags: jquery

Как можно сделать переходы по страницам сайта, как здесь http://vgtrk.com/#page/186
Как эта техника называется?

Comment: std::
@vinnie, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Якорная навигация. Если коротко, то вы всегда сидите на одной странице, а в url меняется якорь (то, что после `#...`), после чего js отслеживает эти изменения и подгружает AJAX-ом нужную страничку. При этом изменения якоря сохраняются в журнале браузера.

Если у клиента отключен js, будет проблема, никто не отправит AJAX запрос. Я обходил это так: ссылки пишем в нормальном виде, а потом js меняет их на якорные. Тогда если js отключен, он ничего не поменяет и ссылки будут действовать.

Comment: А есть какие-нить туторы, которые могут помочь реализовать подобное?) Интересует именно момент анимации страниц

Comment: С анимацией страниц просто — [jquery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), анимируйте `margin` от `0` до `-width` или наоборот, это уже вам придумывать. Туториалов сейчас не подскажу, но они есть =) Ищите якорную навигацию, слайдеры, анимации перехода. Помните только, что анимации, растянутые больше, чем на ~200мс раздражают, особенно когда нужно быстро что-то посмотреть, а оно уже 5 секунд красиво выплывает... Лучше показать пользователю вращающийся кружочек а-ля «загрузка...», если ответ от сервера запаздывает.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо!

Comment: http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework/
рассказывается про подобную технику